# Given $z,s\in \mathbb{D}$, is it always true that $(|z|-|s|)^2\leq \left| \frac{s-z}{1-\overline{s}z} \right|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I have a question regarding an inequality: given two complex numbers in the unit disc $z,s\in \mathbb{D}$, is it always true that
\begin{equation}
(|z|-|s|)^2\leq \left| \frac{s-z}{1-\overline{s}z} \right|^2.
\end{equation}
I tried to proof the result by expanding both sides of the inequality but got nowhere. I also tried using the inverse triangular inequality but I haven't succeeded either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did you find this inequality claimed?

Comment: @Conrad: The LHS is $(z-s)^2=\epsilon^2$?

Comment: @markvs - you are right; I though that LHS was $|z|^2-|s|^2$; my bad

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/428242/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$|1-\bar s z|^2-|s-z|^2=(1-|s|^2)(1-|z|^2)$$ so (by subtracting $1$ from each side and switching signs) the OP inequality is equivalent to $$|1-\bar s z|^2(1-(|z|-|s|)^2) \ge (1-|s|^2)(1-|z|^2)$$.

Now we have:

$$-(1-|z||s|)^2(|z|-|s|)^2 \ge -(|z|-|s|)^2=-|z|^2-|s|^2+2|z||s|$$ while

$$(1-|z||s|)^2=1+|z|^2|s|^2-2|z||s|$$ so adding these two we get

$$(1-|z||s|)^2(1-(|z|-|s|)^2) \ge (1-|s|^2)(1-|z|^2)$$

But $$|1-\bar s z|^2(1-(|z|-|s|)^2) \ge (1-|z||s|)^2(1-(|z|-|s|)^2)$$ and we are done!

Comment: How do you know that $(1-|z||s|)^2 (|z|-|s|)^2 \leq (|z|-|s|)^2$?

Comment: And that $|1-\bar sz|^2 \geq (1-|z||s|)^2$?

Comment: $(1-|z||s|)^2  \le 1$ so $(1-|z||s|)^2 (|z|-|s|)^2 \leq (|z|-|s|)^2$; similarly $|1-\bar s z|  \ge 1-|\bar s z|=1-|s||z|$